# How to check items from database in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-json, android-database, gson

I want load data from **server** into my application, and when users click button save this post (content) from **server** into **`SQLiteDatabse`**.
I want when go to the `activity`, **fist** check `database`, **if exists** this post into `database` change button color.
For this job, I check posts with **Title**! 
That's mean if this post **Title** into `databse` `setBtnColor="R.color.primaryColor"`, another side if this post **Title** **NOT into** `database` `setBtnCOlor="R.color.black"` .

I write below codes, but when running application, show me Force Close error.
 
**DatabaseHelperClass codes:**

```
public boolean checkFavPost(String title) {

    // 1. get reference to writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    // 2. set cursor for read row
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + FavContract.favInfo.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " +
            FavContract.favInfo.FAV_TBL_PTitle + " = ?", new String[]{title});

    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Activity codes:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.post_show_page);

        bindActivity();

        // Initialize
        postShow_favPost = (ShineButton) mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.post_FavImage);
        post_cover = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.postShow_cover_image);
        postShow_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.postShow_title);
        postShow_title2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.postShow_titleBig);
        //postShow_content = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.postShow_content_text);
        postShow_dateTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.postShow_man_date_text);
        postShow_author = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.postShow_man_author_text);
        postShow_category = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.postShow_man_category_text);
        title_sliding = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.post_sliding_title);
        comment_Recyclerview = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.comment_recyclerView);
        post_content_web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.postShow_content_web);

        //Give Data
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (bundle != null) {
            title = bundle.getString("title");
            image = bundle.getString("image");
            content = bundle.getString("content");
            dateTime = bundle.getString("dateTime");
            author = bundle.getString("author");
            category = bundle.getString("category");
            categoryID = bundle.getString("categoryID");
        }

        if (favDB.checkFavPost(title) == true) {
            postShow_favPost.setBtnColor(R.color.colorPrimary);
        } else {
            postShow_favPost.setBtnColor(R.color.black);
        }
```

**Show me error for this line :**

```
if (favDB.checkFavPost(title) == true) {
    postShow_favPost.setBtnColor(R.color.colorPrimary);
} else {
    postShow_favPost.setBtnColor(R.color.black);
}
```

**LogCat error:**

```
09-28 10:38:02.916 2033-2033/com.tellfa.colony E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: com.tellfa.colony, PID: 2033
                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tellfa.colony/com.tellfa.colony.Activities.PostShow_page}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.tellfa.colony.DBhelper.FavHelper.checkFavPost(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.tellfa.colony.DBhelper.FavHelper.checkFavPost(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                     at com.tellfa.colony.Activities.PostShow_page.onCreate(PostShow_page.java:122)
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6020)
                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

My dear friend, I know this error show `NullPointerException`, but I am amateur and my question is how can I fix it?!

Please don't give me negative points, please help me. Thanks all <3

Comment: Something is not there what you are looking for `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.tellfa.colony.DBhelper.FavHelper.checkFavPost(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference` and it is `checkFavPost` probably

Comment: the problem is favDB = null

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain, Thanks man, can you say me how can I fix it? can you send me code? please man

Comment: @PhanVanLinh, Thanks man. it's help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have not initialized the Class.

Please initialize the DatabaseHelperClass with constructor arguments.

DatabaseHelperClass  favDB = new DatabaseHelperClass(this);

Answer (score 0):

Problem is u check the possible value of null

try check it with something like

```
if(value != null){
//and ur code
}
```

also learn something about nullpointexception
[What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)